# Passing custom data through interface c#

Tags: c#, interface

I am being asked to add a new method to my interface. This new method is similar to the other methods, except that they want me to add a custom object as an additional parameter. For example, they want to make the following call:

```
var customData = new object[] { icon, button, title, useDataSource, message };
mimic = viewsIntegrationService.OpenMimic(@"GTCS\Shared\MessageWindow\mmc_MessageBox", null,
                                          mimicBranch, regionNumber, customData);
```

I have an interface called `IViewsIntegrationService` that has a bunch of overloads for the `OpenMimic` method, but I do not have one that takes in a custom object (as `customData` above).

My question is: Even if I add a new method where I add a custom object as the last parameter, wouldn't that method ONLY be used by consumers who know the structure of the object?

It's not like my new method can take any C# object right? It is used to display a custom message box. So how can I write this method so that it satisfies this one person who needs this method, and yet tell all other consumers to not use this method unless it is for message box usage?

I'm new to interface programming, and I am not sure how to do this properly.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm a little confused about the `customData`, why complicate things by making it an `object` array? If it's for message box usage, and there are known attributes and data for it, why not create something explicit?

Comment: This thought did cross my mind as well. But what if I left it as an object array. What problems would I be creating for myself? Is this even possible?

Comment: All you'll be able to know without further investigation is that you have a group of `object`s; that's it. You can't really guarantee what order they're in or that you even got what you expected. You can figure it out though by stinking up your code but you'd be best to avoid it.

Comment: Ok, I will go with the explicit object. I thought there was a special way to do this with objects, but you confirmed that it would require too much additional code to support this. Feel free to put your explanation as an answer if you want. Thanks Chief !

Comment: If you name the new parametert `messageBoxParameters` instead of `customData`, everybody will know its usage. Also, instead of creating a new overload, you could make it an optional [Optional Argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, `messageBoxParameters` is a good name if that's what it's specifically intended to be used for.  In which case, it should probably be something other than an object array.  But it's not unheard of to have a general-purpose interface with an `object[]` or `object` parameter, whose usage is for a concrete implementation and its caller to agree on.  In which case, `customData` may be an appropriate name.  One would need to understand how diverse the concrete implementations of this interface are to judge whether it's appropriate.

Comment: @Joe. Yes, in highly generic and dynamic approaches where you may have to recur to Reflection, you lose the safety of string typing otherwise assured by the compiler.